# Multiple OR conditions not showing correctly

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart

For some reason this "OR" statement is not working:

```
if($product->virtuemart_product_id != 153 || 170 || 171 || 195 || 208){
    //code here
}
```

It works when I only use one ID, but when I add many it doesn't work. Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: You should look at `!in_array()`.

Comment: I thought about doing that, but how do I call the array?

Is it just: `$product->virtuemart_product_id!=array(170,171,153,208,195]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. The correct way is:

```
if($product->virtuemart_product_id != 153 ||
   $product->virtuemart_product_id != 170 || 
   $product->virtuemart_product_id != 171 || 
   $product->virtuemart_product_id != 195 ||
   $product->virtuemart_product_id != 208)
```

It looks messy, but this is the way to do it.

A cleaner approach would be:

```
$arr = [153,170,171,195,208];
if( ! in_array($product->virtuemart_product_id, $arr) )
```

Read more about [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Comment: Thanks mate will be trying that!

Comment: Thanks a lot dude the array version is working! Appreciate it a lot :)

Comment: @MailBlade Happy to help :)